# mainmenu on several form C++ builder

Tags: c++, menu, builder

I want to get one menu to the MainMenu component on eight forms. It is obvious that to copy the event handlers and to do every form saw each other is a bulky variant. As for easier?

Comment: Standard c++ has no menu, form or GUI at all. What framework are you using so that someone can possibly help?

Comment: I write in Rad Studio. I don't have Framework.

Comment: I read about the property Mainmenu of the "Automerge", but I can't do anything